# Is it possible to execute ethereum alarm clock via desktop wallet?

Tags: wallets

Is it possible to execute a scheduled function of [ethereum alarm clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/) via desktop version of Ethereum Wallet. I know the contract can be added to custom contract, but unable to see the methods to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom contract and specify it's ABI in JSON INTERFACE field. The ABI can be taken from Contract ABI area on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b#code).

However, I found an issue in Ethereum Wallet: in case the ABI contains overloaded functions (such as the case with the Ethereum Alarm Clock contract, there are a bunch of scheduleCall functions with different parameter lists), the wallet always shows the same parameter list regardless of what overloaded function you select (apparently it's the first function's parameters defined in the ABI).

The workaround is to edit the ABI and leave only the function that you need to call, e.g.

```
[
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "contractAddress",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "abiSignature",
                "type": "bytes4"
            },
            {
                "name": "callData",
                "type": "bytes"
            },
            {
                "name": "targetBlock",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "requiredGas",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "gracePeriod",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "name": "scheduleCall",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was different. In Mist / Ethereum Wallet you can watch a contract an execute its function, but I was not able to see the execute function of this alarm clock contract. What I asked was is there any alternative way to do it or not?

Comment: @Rajesh do you mean this contract: http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/?

Comment: Yeah, That's right.

Comment: @Rajesh do you also specify JSON INTERFACE when adding a custom contract? You can get the interface from Contract ABI area here https://etherscan.io/address/0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b#code. After doing this I can see 'Schedule Call' function

Comment: @Rajesh I updated my answer. Also included the issue in Ethereum Wallet and the workaround.

Comment: Am not able see any functions. Ref image here https://snag.gy/RmFNOA.jpg

Comment: @Rajesh Try scrolling down. The details are at the bottom and can't be seen until you scroll. Also what version of Ethereum Wallet are you using?

Comment: Ethereum Wallet 0.9.2. Just Latest Events at the bottom. The other space are blank. Is it because my geth is not fully synced with latest block?

Comment: Try waiting till it's synched. Although this contract was created in block 930481 so should already by in your node.

Comment: I wasn't having any Ether in my wallet. Now that I have added, I can see the functions, but there is no Execute function. Can't the execute function be called with this desktop wallet?

Comment: I don't have any ether in my account. Can still see the function list and the Execute button https://snag.gy/aQujnb.jpg

Comment: All I see is so many Schedule methods only, which of the method to be called to execute a scheduled contract so that we can receive some ether for executing it.

Comment: The execution of scheduled requests has many intricacies. You need to read their documentation to understand how to execute requests and get paid. It's a multistage process. Besides that I see no transactions to the production contract here https://etherscan.io/address/0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b so not sure if you can make any money out of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to participate in execution of Ethereum Alarm Clock contracts, the recommended way is to use TimeNode (either CLI or desktop version). [Here's tutorial how to run it.](https://blog.chronologic.network/how-to-prove-day-ownership-to-be-a-timenode-3dc1333c74ef)

You indeed need to load keystore file in Electron app downloaded from GitHub: https://github.com/chronologic/eth-alarm-clock-dapp/releases (it works on Windows, OSX and Linux).